# The maths/physics in "The Amazing Spider Man"

Tags: soft-question

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does Peter Parkers formula represent?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20675/what-does-peter-parkers-formula-represent)

I just saw the trailer for the new Spider Man movie and couldn't help but notice the image after the guy says "How did you come up with this". So here is a transcript (the last part can't be seen):

$$\eqalign{
  & \frac{{d\log \Phi }}{{dt}} = \alpha \left( {1 - g{{\left( {\frac{\Phi }{k}} \right)}^\beta }} \right)  \cr 
  & \Phi  = K\sum\limits_i {\prod\limits_j {\exp \left( {\frac{{{q^j}{{\left( {1 - {E_a}} \right)}^{j - 1}}}}{{\left( {j - 1} \right)!\left( {1 - {{\left( {1 - {E_a}} \right)}^{j - 1}}} \right)}}} \right)} } \log a \cdots  \cr} $$

[image]

Does it resemble, make sense, relate to any real math? (I dont really see any $i$ index inside the expression for example).
I actually laughed at the sigma, pi, exp triad.
I put this in pshysics.SE from a sugestion from math.SE

> On the other hand, the notation looks awfully like that of a (thermodynamic) partition function, and thus this might be more appropriate as a question on physics.SE instead of here...

Comment: The math.SE question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/107265/

Comment: The formulae look like probability formulae. So its most probably statistical thermodynamics. In that case, the sigmapiexp triad is pretty normal.